# How To Stretch/Scale Figure Size in Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

How do I stretch the current figure size in matplotlib? For example, make it twice as wide but keeping the same height.

NOTE: I do not want to just set the figsize to something new. I want to double the existing width, whatever it is.  This is not a duplicate question of how to set the figure size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
fig_width, fig_height = plt.gcf().get_size_inches()
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(fig_width*2, fig_height))
```

You can get the default, or current, figure size parameters using `plt.gcf().get_size_inches()`.

Then set a new figure size by scaling these values and creating a figure with `figsize` as an argument. In this case, the width is doubled but height kept the same.

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it solved the problem.

Comment: @Tyler2P good point. Done